# Use C# to call AS400 program and select file from QTEMP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a ASP.Net app to call AS400 program in order to create a file under QTEMP. But when I try to select this file from QTEMP, it does not exist.

I understand the reason: call program and select file are different jobs. I cannot access other job's QTEMP.

I do not know much about the AS400, the only way I can find out is to create this file under another library other than QTEMP. But it will impact my other app functions which I do not want to do.

I am using cwbx.dll to call the AS400 program and then I am using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries to select the file from QTEMP. Obviously they are two connections opened. I am not sure if under as400 concept, they may be two separate jobs.

Here is the function to call the program:

```
As400Caller1.CallAs400Program("myProgram", "myLibrary", paramsList1);
```

Here is the CallAs400Program function:

```
public void CallAs400Program(string programName, string libraryName, List<AS400Param> parameters) {

            try
            {
                system.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd);

                //check connection
                if (system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) == 1)
                {
                    //create a program object and link to the system
                    Program program = new Program();
                    program.LibraryName = libraryName;
                    program.ProgramName = programName;
                    program.system = system;

                    //create a parameter collection associated with the program and pass data
                    ProgramParameters prms = new ProgramParameters();
                    foreach (AS400Param p in parameters)
                    {
                        prms.Append(p.ParameterName, cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, p.ParameterLength);
                        if (!p.OutParam)
                        {
                            prms[p.ParameterName].Value = AS400ParamStringConverter.ConvertASCIItoEBCDIC(p.ParameterValue.PadRight(p.ParameterLength, ' '));
                        }
                    }

                    //call the program
                    try
                    {
                        program.Call(prms);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (system.Errors.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (cwbx.Error error in system.Errors)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }

                        if (program.Errors.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (cwbx.Error error in program.Errors)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No AS400 Service connection");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) == 1)
                    system.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
            }
        }
```

Here is my select SQL code:

```
 try
    {
        List<TableRowModel> dataList = new List<TableRowModel>();
        string library = "QTEMP";
        string cmdText = $@"SELECT * FROM {library}.myFile";
        iDB2Command command = new iDB2Command(cmdText);
        command.Connection = IDB2Context.Current;
        iDB2DataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

        }
        return dataList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Exception throw:

`myFile in QTEMP type *FILE not found`.

How can I use C# to solve the issue of accessing other Jobs QTEMP?

Comment: Do you know what the AS/400 program is doing?  In many cases native programs are doing something akin to running a `SELECT` statement, or part of a process for building one (temporary work files).  Since most of the languages used to write programs on the AS/400 are pretty niche, it might be better to translate it to something more widely used.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you for the reply. It does a table creation into the QTEMP and some JOINs and INSERT INTO. They are inside EXEC SQL block.

Comment: It sounds like you can probably just turn that into a permanent view.  Otherwise, if using a view would be too resource intensive (or possibly have lock contention issues), the usual thing to do would be to create a temp table via [`DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html) (this is session-specific, but "session" is going to be the lifetime of your connection to the database).  Tricks like creating and returning it from a stored procedure are also possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QTEMP` is session specific...you can't access it from another job..

Consider an using an SQL Stored procedure that you can call from .NET.

The stored proc can call the RPG program and the return the results from the file in `QTEMP` all in a single call.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So you mean I need to create a Stored Procedure to call another Program and inside this Program I need to select the file from QTEMP? I am not understand how does the JOB session be passed from connection to connection. I guess when I close my connection, the file in QTEMP is gone.

Comment: QTEMP is a pseudo-schema. There is a separate QTEMP for every job in the system. In this case, a job is a connection. When the connection is closed, the job ends and that job's QTEMP is deleted. By creating a new stored procedure that will do both things (run the RPG program, SELECT from the QTEMP table) this can be run in one connection, and thus have access to that connection's QTEMP.